# Select data frame based on condition without for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 data frames `df1`, `df2`, `df3`

Based on year condition, I want to select one of them

My current approach is using for-loops. Can I do this better?

```
  if(year == "2008"){
    df <- df1
  } else if (year == "2009"){
    df <- df2
  } else{
    df <- df3
  }
```

Comment: but you're already not using loops..? switch works too `df <- switch(as.character(year), '2008' = df1, '2009' = df2, df3)`

Comment: @rawr: there's a for loop above this which runs and takes year values one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just keep them in a list. Something like :

```
lst <- list('2008'= df1, '2009' = df2, '2010' = df3)
```

and then based on the `year` I would subset it. Basically now you replace your entire code with just one line.

```
lst[year]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ifelse approach:

```
df = ifelse(year == 2008, df1, ifelse(year == 2009, df2, df3))
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it didn't work, are you sure it works for you?

Comment: Well, that is a basic idea how to use conditional ifelse(). It really depends where is your dataframes are saved. The best solution would be to store it in a single dataframe and then subset it based on a year or store it in a list.